# add_filter > posts_where works partially

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, filters, meta-query

I started to work with this code: [Used with meta_query in query_posts works slowly](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/204749/81500)

and i changed the code and started to work with `add_filter`

```
function filter_where($where = ''){
    global $wpdb;

    if($_GET['fromNumberOfRooms'] > 0) {
        $where .= " AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'number-of-rooms' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value >= {$_GET['fromNumberOfRooms']})";
    }
    if($_GET['upToNumberOfRooms'] > 0) {
    $where .= " AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'number-of-rooms' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value <= {$_GET['upToNumberOfRooms']})";
    }
    if($_GET['fromSize'] > 0) {
        $where .= " AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'size' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value >= {$_GET['fromSize']})";
    }
    if($_GET['upToSize'] > 0) {
    $where .= " AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'size' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value <= {$_GET['upToSize']})";
    }
    if($_GET['fromPrice'] > 0) {
        $where .= " AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'price' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value >= {$_GET['fromPrice']})";
    }
    if($_GET['upToPrice'] > 0) {
        $where .= " AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'price' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value <= {$_GET['upToPrice']})";
    }

    return $where;

}

add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
```

But now it only works if I filter the `price` or `size` or `number-of-rooms` if I try to filter all the variables does not show me anything

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like it would produce meaningful SQL, keys cannot hold different values at the same time (that's why JOINs are usually required in complex queries).

Also using `$_GET` global in queries is **horribly insecure**, if you have this anywhere near live site you should remove it immediately.

You earlier question used `WP_Query`, if it did work at all (even if slowly) you should start with studying SQL it produced and optimize from that point.